# can objects be instances of multiple type?

Tags: javascript, instanceof

```
function Hero(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
var h = new Hero('Leonardo');
var a = h instanceof Hero;
var b = h instanceof Object;`
```

Here I can understand that a will be 'true'. But when I check in Firefox console, b is also coming as 'true'. Why is this happening?

Comment: Every object is an instance of `Object` only.

Answer (score 1):

An object is an instance of everything on its prototype chain:

```js
function Animal() {
}

function Cat() {
}

function Dog() {
}

Cat.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
Dog.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);

var felix = new Cat();
snippet.log("Felix");
snippet.log("Object - " + (felix instanceof Object));
snippet.log("Animal - " + (felix instanceof Animal));
snippet.log("Cat    - " + (felix instanceof Cat));
snippet.log("Dog    - " + (felix instanceof Dog));

snippet.log("-----------");

var spike = new Dog();
snippet.log("Spike");
snippet.log("Object - " + (spike instanceof Object));
snippet.log("Animal - " + (spike instanceof Animal));
snippet.log("Cat    - " + (spike instanceof Cat));
snippet.log("Dog    - " + (spike instanceof Dog));
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is due to `Prototype Inheritance`, every `Array`, `Function`,etc  meets upto the Object as an grand Parent/Ultimate parent of every thing

```
a = [];
b = function(){}
a instanceof Object // true
b instanceof Object // true
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript all native function are inherited from base class Object. So all objects are instance of Object.

Check Array, String,  all are instance of Object.

A must known fact in javascript.